# typeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'Wifip2pManager.init

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-layout, react-native

he instalado "**npm install react-native-wifi-p2p --save**"
el codigo que mortrare lo he obtenido de "**https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-p2p**" .la linea 11 es el que tiene el error, ya que, si yo borro la linea 11 todo funciona correctamente. En el dispositivo android me muestra en siguiente error: "typeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'Wifip2pManager.init'",,. no se si estoy haciendo bien, quiza a alguien que intento hacer funcionar le salio el mismo error... Ayudaaaa
[image: la linea 11 es el que tiene el error,]

[image: Error en el dispositivo android]

Comment: Luego de ejecutar el codigo me aparece el siguiente error: "typeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'Wifip2pManager.init') ", si a alguien tuvo algun problema similar, podria ayudarme , gracias de antemano .... ha estoy importando : linea 3: "import {initialize,isSuccessfulInitialize} from 'react-native-wifi-p2p'; "

Comment: Hola fhk, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar información adicional, no la agregues como comentario. Agrega además la traza completa del error, en qué momento se genera, etc (de ser posible, copia y pega el texto, no saques un pantallazo), ya que no queda claro el por qué se genera. Por último, te sugiero que revises [ask] para tener una mejor idea de como puedes mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Leyendo el principio de la documentación dicen esto "This library will not work on emulator. If you want to use this library, you should test working it on real devices." te hago una pregunta, estás probando en el emulador o en tu dispositivo?

Comment: Si, estoy probando en mi celular directamente...